# vsftpd anonymous directory shows nothing

Tags: linux, redhat, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using vsftpd on Red Hat Linux. I want to enable anonymous user login. After all the configurations, I can login without username and password. However I see nothing in the user's home directory. Here are my configurations:

vsftpd.conf:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
anon_root=/var/www/html/drawbmp
```

user ftp in /etc/passwd:

```
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/www/html/drawbmp:/sbin/nologin
```

The permission of `/var/www/html/drawbmp` is 755. There are several bmp pictures in it, they have 777 permission;

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Any relevant messages in your vsftpd logs ? Do you have SELinux enabled and if so have you looked in /var/log/audit/audit.log for relevant AVC denied messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My blind guess is that `ftp_home_dir` SELinux boolean prevents this.

Try `semanage boolean -l | grep "ftp_home"`, if it returns `off off`, then please try

```
semanage boolean ftp_home_dir on
```

If that resolves your problem, you could then take vsftpd virtual users into use and use only those accounts for FTP, and then disable the now-permitted home directory access via FTP with `semanage boolean ftp_home_dir off`.